# npm, node, ipython all return "exec format error"

Tags: node.js, archlinux

The title pretty much says it. I'm on Arch Linux, all pkgs updated, running `zsh`.
All three - `node`, `npm` and `ipython` - fail with a simple `zsh: exec format error`.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

`uname -a` says:

`Linux localhost 3.8.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 6 08:44:16 CEST 2013 i686 GNU/Linux`

My `/etc/pacman.conf` is:

```
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
#GPGDir      = /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - -f %u > %o
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
#UseDelta    = 0.7
Architecture = auto

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options
#UseSyslog
#Color
#TotalDownload
CheckSpace
#VerbosePkgLists

# By default, pacman accepts packages signed by keys that its local keyring
# trusts (see pacman-key and its man page), as well as unsigned packages.
SigLevel    = Required DatabaseOptional
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional
#RemoteFileSigLevel = Required

# NOTE: You must run `pacman-key --init` before first using pacman; the local
# keyring can then be populated with the keys of all official Arch Linux
# packagers with `pacman-key --populate archlinux`.

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

# The testing repositories are disabled by default. To enable, uncomment the
# repo name header and Include lines. You can add preferred servers immediately
# after the header, and they will be used before the default mirrors.

#[testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

#[community-testing]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs
```

(note: this *might* belong on Unix.SE)

Comment: Post the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/pacman.conf`. Did you have these problems with other packages?

Comment: @Blender I posted the info. As for other packages.. hm, no. I just reinstalled IPython and it now throws an `ImportError`, saying 'no module named `pkg_resources`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed the problem.

- As for Node.js and `npm`, all I did was remove (`pacman -Rnsc`) Node.js and reinstall.
- For `ipython` I reinstalled `distribute`.

That's all.

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps any future lost soul ending up here: I saw this issue trying to use a x64 binary on a 32-bit linux. Grabbing the correct binaries definitely fixed it, which I assume is what helped the OP since a reinstall fixed their problem.